# How can i get the current time of the song playing in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

This is my code:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.author


let spotify = user.presence.activities.filter(x => x.name == 'Spotify' && x.type == 'LISTENING')[0]
const sp = spotify.status
console.log(sp)
```

Is there a way to get the current time of the song on spotify and display it in seconds/minutes.

if the current song is at the 23 sec. it will display 0:23 in the console.

Discord js v13.

Comment: You can read `currentTime` property on html audio element

Answer (score 1):

You can read `currentTime` from audio element

```js
function logCurrentTime() {
  let audioElement = document.getElementById('audio')
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerText = audioElement.currentTime
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="logCurrentTime()">Click to log current time</button>

  <p id='currentTime'></p>
  <audio id="audio" controls autoplay src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg" />
</body>
```

Ref :- [MediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/ActivityTimestamps). In this case, `spotify.timestamps.start` will be the time the user started the activity (as a [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

PS: The docs are your best friend! If there's anything you're ever unsure about, go [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/general/welcome)!

Comment: I've read the docs, that's why i came here. Timestamps.start displays the date when the user started listening to music, NOT the current/second of the song.